# Drip lines not working

Tags: irrigation, drip-system

Recently moved into a house that has drip line irrigation. There are 4 drip lines on one valve. However, when I turn on that valve, only two of the lines work.

The other 2 lines do not even have water flowing to the front of the line where it comes out of the ground. Any suggestions on what could be wrong? I'm not extremely knowledgeable with irrigation systems but know the basics.

Comment: Pictures would help a lot.

Comment: A broken pipe also comes to mind - you might be dumping water into the ground, but not leaving it open long enough to see.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the non-working pipes are buried, it's likely that they are broken, or blocked or both. Unless of course there's an inline valve you've not found...

Drippers and other small irrigation fittings can also block easily. Some systems even recommend an inline filter leading up to the drippers, to prevent blockage.